# iOS - How to insert a character in a specific place inside a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have an url that looks something like this: "http://www.thisIsMyLink.com/afAFFgsfFGsgsdfgds.jpg"

The thing is that I need to add "_s" to the end of the url just before the ".jpg". So what I need would be this: http://www.thisIsMyLink.com/afAFFgsfFGsgsdfgds_s.jpg

I found one way to put specific characters inside a string like this:

```
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:myUrl];
[mu insertString:@"_s" atIndex:5];
```

which will add the "_s" in the 5th character inside the string. The problem is that I don't know every time the length of the link because of the identifier which comes before the ".jpg", so what I need is to always place the "_s" 4 characters before the end so that it appears just before the ".jpg".

How can I do that?

Thanks for reading my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another one that would work for **any** extension (.jpeg for instance):

```
NSString *test = @"www.thisIsMyLink.com/afAFFgsfFGsgsdfgds.jpg";
NSString *ext = [test pathExtension]; // This is .jpg in this case
NSString *out = [[[test stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingString:@"_s"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:ext];
```

So the logic here is:

1. Get your path's extension
2. Delete the extension
3. Add your string
4. Add the extension

That way you avoid relying on any assumptions (such as that you always have a 3 letter extension). Worst case scenario, to have no extension at all and end with a path with your string appended in the end of it. I hope that this helped.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:myUrl];
[mu insertString:@"_s" atIndex:[mu length] - 4];
```

You should ensure, though, that `[mu length]` is always >= 4.

There might be clever ways to do that, but you do not specify how you get the original url from. One option would be using `stringWithFormat` to build your string modularily.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
[mu insertString:@"_s" atIndex:[mu length] - 3];
```

Untested.

Comment: so every time i have to calculate the length of the string. However i am pretty sure that in the past i had seen a method to put a character counting from the end of the string..

Comment: @user1511244 It's best to stuff it before the extension in the way Alladinian showed above. The `- 3` will fail when you work with tiff e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitive replacing of the last instance of ".jpg" with "_s.jpg". This avoids url mangling in the case where you have ".jpg" somewhere else in the url for some reason.

```
NSString *extension = @".jpg";
NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:myUrl];
[mu insertString@"_s" atIndex[[[url lowercaseString] rangeOfString:extension options:NSBackwardsSearch].location];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` has a method called `length` which returns the length of the string. Subtract the length of the extension (4), and you have your start index.